# Get User Activity and Game Status

Tags: discord.net

I am writing my first bot and I want it to check the user's activity status and do some operations based on
what they are playing. The bot gets the user, but user Status is always offline and
therefore, it can't get their activities.

I have Server members and Presence intent both enabled.

This is my startup code, do I need to add something here?

```
   static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private CommandService _commands;
    private IServiceProvider _services;
   
    public async Task RunBotAsync()
    {

        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _commands = new CommandService();

        _services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton(_client)
            .AddSingleton(_commands)
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        string token = "my token"; 

        _client.Log += _client_Log;
   
        await RegisterCommandsAsync();

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);

        await _client.StartAsync();
        
        await Task.Delay(-1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
    
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private CommandService _commands;
        private IServiceProvider _services;
       
        public async Task RunBotAsync()
        {
    
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _commands = new CommandService();
    
            _services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
                    {
                        GatewayIntents =  GatewayIntents.AllUnprivileged |
                        GatewayIntents.GuildPresences | GatewayIntents.GuildMembers
                    }))
                .AddSingleton(_commands)
                .BuildServiceProvider();
    
            string token = "my token"; 
    
            _client.Log += _client_Log;
       
            await RegisterCommandsAsync();
    
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
    
            await _client.StartAsync();
            
            await Task.Delay(-1);
    
        }
```